# How to get total user count in rateable?

Tags: php, laravel

I implemented a rating system looking at the [rateable laravel](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable/blob/master/src/Rateable/Rateable.php) package and it works as it should. I have avg rating for each product but want to add besides it the number of users that rated that product. For instance an avg rating of 4.5 that was rated by 5 users.

The package has userSumRating below which outputs the sum of a user's rating but that is not the same with what i am looking for

```
public function userSumRating()
{
    return $this->ratings()->where('user_id', \Auth::id())->sum('rating');
}
```

I have tried a couple of things but none has worked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well got it working. First made a user only able to rate once with subsequent ratings as updates then

```
$this['count'] = Advert::with(
    [
        'ratings' => function ($query) {
            $query->count('rating');
         }
    ])
    ->where('slug', $slug)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->first();
```

then in twig

```
{{ count.ratings|length }}
```

Answer (score 1):

After looking at package you have mentioned in the question, `ratings()` gives all the ratings associated with the product so you can count those ratings like this:

```
$product->ratings()->count();
```

I am not sure but this might work. I have assumed user rates particular product only once.

Comment: $product->ratings() returns a querybuilder and i would expect this to be incorrect and i would always use sql count to do these operations.

Answer (score 1):

I would utilise group by and count from SQl terminology. This is rough idea, not ranned but i think this should solve it. Group by squashes all rows with the same user into one, then we just count how many there is after that.

```
public function usersRated()
{
    return $this->ratings()->groupBy('user_id')->count('user_id');
}
```